# How to post a x-www-form-urlencoded request using http.request()

Tags: javascript, playfab

I am developing a multiplayer game and I am required to use **Microsoft Azure playfab's Cloud Script (Legacy)** feature for a Discord OAuth2 authorization code grant.

To do this I need to send a `x-www-form-urlencoded` POST request with the following parameters:

```js
client_id = "988833332445978624",
client_secret = "CLIENT_SECRET_HERE",
grant_type = "authorization_code",
redirect_uri = "http://localhost:8080/discord",
code = "OAUTH2_CODE_HERE"
```

I have tried utilizing the `fetch()` method, but it appears that **Azure Playfab's Cloud Script (Legacy)** only supports requests made with `http.request()` according to [their documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/playfab/features/automation/cloudscript/writing-custom-cloudscript#intermediate-overview-globals-and-advanced-arguments).

After looking through the docs I still can not figure out how to send a `x-www-form-urlencoded` **POST** request with `http.request()`. If anybody could help me figure this out that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x-www-form-urlencoded` is really only a type of formatting, you don't need any special logic apart from correctly preparing your body contents

```
var headers = {
  "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
};

var body = {
  client_id: "988833332445978624",
  client_secret: "CLIENT_SECRET_HERE",
  grant_type: "authorization_code",
  redirect_uri: "http://localhost:8080/discord",
  code: "OAUTH2_CODE_HERE"
};

var url = "https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token";
var content = Object.keys(body).map(function(key){
    return encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(body[key]);
}).join('&');

var httpMethod = "post";
var contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

var response = http.request(url, httpMethod, content, contentType, headers);

return { responseContent: response };
```